# Character set mismatch in database migration

Tags: mysql, migration, character-set

I have an old database (MySQL 5.1.58) that I want to migrate to a new installation (MySQL 8.0.26). When I just use

```
oldserver ~$ mysqldump mydatabase > file.sql
newserver ~$ mysql mydatabase < file.sql
```

This works fine, except for the character set. I have some records with non-ASCII characters, and I *think* the old server is on iso-8859-1 (how can I know for sure). The new server is UTF-8, because I have set `.my.cnf` to:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
```

I tried to convert the resulting file before import using

```
~$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 file.sql -o file.utf8.sql
```

But that didn't seem to work (I only get more `À` characters). I can hexdump the dumpfile, and I see hex characters `c3 a2 e2 82 ac cb 9c` being rendered as `â€˜` on my terminal.

How can I correctly dump this database into a new UTF-8 based server?

I am in full control of the target database server, but (as it is still in use) I do not want to touch the source.

**Update** I dumped my database with

```
oldserver ~$ mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 mydatabase > file.sql
```

and it now dumps correctly. When inspecting the file, I see valid UTF-8 characters in the dump.

Importing it still fails though.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the default character set on both commands.  For flexibility, use `utf8mb4`, not `latin1`.

Probably you also changed versions in the process.  At some point MySQL changed the default from latin1 to utf8mb4.  Were those two commands done on different servers?  Or were they done across the wire?  I ask because my version comment applies to both mysqldump and mysql.